# Creating image asset in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, assets

I am trying to create an image asset in Android studio. I am facing problem at 2 levels.
First, when I launch Asset Studio and select an image with Asset Type set as 'Launcher Icon', asset is created inside mipmap folder instead of drawable folder.

[image]

So I changed Asset type to 'Action Bar and Tab icons'.But it causes image to appear as white blocks.

[image]

Please advise what I am supposed to do.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305425/android-studio-adding-images/34305659 it will help you to add images to your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first problem, the behavior is correct.You have to save your ic_launcher in the mipmap folder
[See android documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#mipmap)

The 'Action Bar and Tab icons' is for icons only, and icons are defined by Android to use only one color