# Android Studio Adding Images

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I am new to android  studio. Can any one tell me what is the best way to add images as in eclipse?  We have different folder like mdpi, xdpi .. Can any one tell me what is the best way to add images and size also?

```
 I am trying with new->image asset but is this right way? what should be image size
```

..  as in eclipse we are adding directly to res->mdpi,xdpi

What size  should i take? What is asset type in that tool it giving only 3 option ie icon, action and tab, notification which one to be take?

Comment: You can do it in android studio as well. Simply add your images to the drawable folders.

Comment: is we have use tool ? drwable->new->image asset-?

Comment: what size should we take for full screen image say ? splash screen

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/

Comment: Size is different according to screen size.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya in studio we dont have res

Comment: any standard size should we follow ? as image asset tool making max size is 196*196

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Drawable Folder: How to put Images for Multiple dpi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294287/android-studio-drawable-folder-how-to-put-images-for-multiple-dpi/29294557#29294557)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just copy the image:

[image]

and paste it into drawable:

[image]

You can also drag and drop.

Now, for different sizes, just make a folder with the appropriate names. **Go into project view first**:

[image]

Then, see these little folders in the res?

[image]

Place each image into each folder. Here are the different size directories:

```
drawable-mdpi for medium-density

drawable-hdpi for high-density

drawable-xhdpi for extra-high-density

drawable-xxhdpi for extra-extra-high-density
```

**Thats it.**

If this helped, make sure to accept it by pushing the checkmark. If you have more questions, feel free to ask, I am happy to help!

Edit to question:

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).  
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).  
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).  
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

Comment: hi can give image size like mdpi shld have480*680

Comment: @andro Sure! `320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).  
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).  
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).  
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).`

Comment: i am using 1850*1370 still it showing some space to right and left side

Comment: @andro This happens quite often. It means your image is listed in the `src` attribute. Instead, put it in the `background` attribute. :)

Comment: @andro Another thing you can do is follow my edit, and put it into the appropriate directories through re-sizing. This will show you [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747489/android-handling-images-size-for-multiple-screens). If I helped, make sure to accept my answer!

Comment: background done the trick , may i know what ratio shuld i follow

Comment: @andro What do you mean by ratio? The size you want to display depends on...well...what you want to display, so, just change the height and width to a `dp` size that fits your needs! :)

Comment: say i want to display full screen image then what would be size ? h * w ?

Comment: both , want to support all most all device

Comment: @andro Very long process... Make 8 more xml layouts per layout...Then, change each layout based on size...So, you'll be better off just getting the size of the screen through java (just seach up how to get screen size in android) and then setting the size of your image to that size.

Comment: r u kidding me 8 xml ? i think by putting 4 drwable will do

Comment: @RuchirBaronia hi, copying via shortcuts is working fine. But when I drag and drop into the folder, for a single image, it shows a move dialog but the 'Ok' button is unresponsive!! And the whole application seems stuck and after some time typing enter key, it shows a dialog for refactor for that image. Is this a new bug? I'm surprised the drag and drop is having issues!

I'm on OS X 10.10 and Android Studio 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can directly Add your images in drawable folder
OR
If you have requirement for multi size images then use drawable size categories like.

drawable-mdpi         for medium-density

drawable-hdpi          for high-density

drawable-xhdpi         for extra-high-density

drawable-xxhdpi        for extra-extra-high-density

It can be found in detail [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)