# How to create a multi-colored action bar icon with Asset Studio

Tags: android, android-asset-studio

When I create an action bar icon from an image asset in Asset Studio, the icon is always of only one color even if the original image is multi-colored.

I have found in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919692/creating-image-asset-in-android-studio) that `icons are defined by Android to use only one color` but 
Android default drawable assets are multi-colored e.g. @android:drawable/ic_menu_delete

So how can I create a custom multi-colored icon or why can't I do that?

Answer (score 0):

if your use colored icon,Try to use programmatically

```
view_action_bar.itemIconTintList=null
```

where view_action_bar is view id on your xml